# “fun off this game” vs “fun out of this game”

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

Considering I'm having casual a conversation.
Which one should I choose? Are both correct?

> We've had a lot of fun off this game

Or

> We've had a lot of fun out of this game

Answer (score 2):

To me the first one sounds wrong. The second one is better. It probably wouldn't sound wrong in a conversation but when thinking about it, it seems slightly off.
You could try:

> "We've had a lot of fun with this game"

Some other options are available:

"We've had a lot of fun playing this game", "We've got a lot of fun out of this game." or "We've got a lot of fun from this game"

The last two options are British English. If you want American English, replace "got" with "gotten"

Answer (score 1):

These both statements seem grammatically wrong to me. I would rather say 'We had a lot of fun playing this game.' You need to address what you did with the game which was fun i.e. *playing*.  You also do not need to use 'have' in this sentence.